# XYPlot with ListView has a black background instead of transparent background

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to make the background of my ListView transparent. I've figured out how to do it in all cases except for my XYPlot when the ListView is not moving. No matter what I try, the background always seems to be black when stopped (it is transparent when moving).

Here is a picture of what I am working with:

[image]

Here is my xml for the listview:

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="3sp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
/>
```

Here is my xml for the XYPlot:

```
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
android:id="@+id/trend_plot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

Here is my formatting for the graph:

```
//clear the previous info
graph.clear();

//Remove the legend
graph.getLayoutManager().remove(graph.getLegendWidget());

//Remove lines and format
Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
graph.getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.setBackgroundPaint(backgroundPaint);
graph.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getCursorLabelBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getCursorLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getDomainGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getDomainSubGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getRangeGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().getRangeSubGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
graph.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelOrientation(-400);
graph.getRangeLabelWidget().getLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
graph.getRangeLabelWidget().setText("Votes");
graph.getDomainLabelWidget().getLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
graph.getDomainLabelWidget().setText("Time");
graph.getTitleWidget().setPaddingTop(20);
graph.getTitleWidget().setPaddingBottom(20);
graph.getTitleWidget().getLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
graph.getTitleWidget().setText("Popularity");
graph.setRangeBoundaries(0, 100, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

Has anyone dealt with something like this before? I'm just trying to make the graph background transparent all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

to the Listview?

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="3sp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    plot.setBorderStyle(Plot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);
                    plot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    plot.setPlotPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    plot.setGridPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    plot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    plot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint()
                            .setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint()
                            .setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    LayoutManager lm = plot.getLayoutManager();
                    XYGraphWidget g = plot.getGraphWidget();
                    // plot = new XYPlot(getApplicationContext(), "",
                    // Plot.RenderMode.USE_MAIN_THREAD);
                    g.setGridPaddingLeft(0);
                    g.setGridPaddingRight(0);
                    g.setMarginLeft(0);
                    g.position(-0.5f, XLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_RIGHT,
                            -0.5f, YLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_BOTTOM,
                            AnchorPosition.CENTER);
                    g.setSize(new SizeMetrics(0, SizeLayoutType.FILL, 0,
                            SizeLayoutType.FILL));
```